# AJAX within a modal inserting a form in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

Been struggling with this for about 4 hours, I'm attempting to have a modal drop down (Twitter bootstrap modal) that contains a form to create a Company. This is built in CodeIgniter.

I'm having issues with input type="submit" and input type="button".

I only have 1 required field, which is Company Name. If I use input type="button", the validation will fire correctly inside of the modal, however the form will only INSERT just the company name, along with company_id, user_id, active, and cdate.

Now if I use input type="submit", all the data inserts fine. However, the validation breaks and I get a "Page cannot be found" after clicking "Create Company", the data is still inserting though.

Any ideas? Thanks! New to AJAX...

My AJAX function:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#create_btn').live('click', function(){
      //we'll want to move to page specific files later

    var name = $('#name').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: CI_ROOT + "members/proposals/add_client",
        type: 'post',
        data: {'name': name },
        complete: function(r){
          var response_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(r.responseText);

          if (response_obj.status == 'SUCCESS')
          {
              window.location = CI_ROOT + response_obj.data.redirect;
          }
          else
          {       
            $('#error_message2').html(response_obj.data.err_msg);
          }
        },
    });     


  });

});
```

My controller function which handles the insert:

```
    function add_client()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Company Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    load_model('client_model', 'clients');
    load_model('industry_model');

    $user_id = get_user_id();
    $company_id = get_company_id();

    if (!$user_id || !$company_id) redirect('home');

    if ($_POST)
    {

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        { 

        $fields = $this->input->post(null , TRUE);


        $fields['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $fields['company_id'] = $company_id;
        $fields['active'] = 1;
        $fields['cdate'] = time();


        $insert = $this->clients->insert($fields);

            if ($insert)
            {
                $this->message->set('alert alert-success', '<h4>Company has been added</h4>');
                header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->message->set('alert alert-error', '<h4>There was an issue adding this Company, please try again</h4>');
            }                   


        }


        else
        {  
            $err_msg =  validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>'); 
            $retval = array('err_msg'=>$err_msg);
            $this->ajax_output($retval, false);
        }

    }

    $this->data['industries'] = array(0=>'Select Industry...') + $this->industry_model->dropdown('industry');   

    $this->insertMethodJS();
    $this->template->write_view('content',$this->base_path.'/'.build_view_path(__METHOD__), $this->data);           
    $this->template->render();
}
```

And finally, my view:

```
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="milestone" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 600px !important;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add a Company</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'members/proposals/add_client', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'client_form'));?>   

    <div id="error_message2"></div> 

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span5">

            <input type="hidden" name="cdate" id="cdate" value="" />

            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name: <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Abbreviation:<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="abbreviation" name="abbreviation" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>      


            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Image: </label>
                <div class="controls">
                        <input type="file" name="client_image" size="20" /> 
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>  

            <div class="span5">

            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Website:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="website" name="website" value=""/> 
                </div>
            </div>  

       </div>

    </div>  



<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5" style="margin-top: 25px;">

    <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <p><strong>Client</strong></p>
            </div>
    </div>  


    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Address 1:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" value=""/>
            </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Address 2:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="address2" name="address2" value=""/>
            </div>
    </div>      

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">City:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city"  value=""/>
            </div>
    </div>  


    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">State:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?= form_dropdown('state', usa_state_list(), set_value('state'), 'id=state');  ?>     
            </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Zip:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" value=""/>
            </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Country:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?= form_dropdown('country', country_list(), set_value('country'), 'id=country');  ?>    
            </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="create_btn">Create Company</button>
  </div>
 </form> 
</div>
```

So again, to summarize. With input type="button", my validation works great within the modal and only the Company Name is inserting into the database along with company_id, user_id, active, and cdate.

Now, with input type="submit", all data inserts great, however validation fails and I get a redirect to a page cannot be found.

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your ajax function call.

You need to prevent the form from firing (and thus submitting via post to the url in action):

Change:

```
$('#create_btn').live('click', function(){
```

To:

```
$('#create_btn').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

This **should** fix the issue. If it doesn't, let me know and I'll do more digging. I would also recommend switching `live` to `on` so that you future-proof yourself. `on` handles the same stuff as live, bind, etc. in a single function with more efficiency.

Edit: To explain what's going on (and why you must use `e.preventDefault();`), it is because `<input type="submit">` will actually submit the form to the url specified in the `<form>` tag's `action` attribute. Thus, what's happening with your code is that your javascript is running as soon as you click the button, and then the native browser submit event is occurring immediately afterwards.

Comment: Great, this did fix the validation. However, I still cannot get all the other input fields to insert into the DB...

Comment: Also, my redirect isn't working. When I click "Create Company", it simply does nothing and keeps the modal open. It is storing the Company Name in the database along w/ those other ID's and cdate. I don't understand why name is inserting and not the other fields. I've tried adding the other fields to the validation

Comment: First, you should reference `$_POST` as `$this->input->post()`. Then, to debug, try changing the `if($_POST)` block to do `die(var_dump($this->input->post()));` as the first thing. Then `alert()` the response object in your `complete:` event inside the ajax call. This will tell you what you're actually sending to the script.

Comment: Hmm having trouble setting this up, I'll get it though.. thanks for the help will give rep!

Comment: I'd encourage you to just vote up and not mark correct... someone else might have more insight on this. I might be able to provide a more concrete debugging example later. You should start off simple however and increment the complexity so that you know when something goes wrong.

Comment: I can't up vote until I have 15 rep =/ wanted to give you some karma and i think this is the only way...

Comment: Now you do. Sorry about that! :)